# Using Builder instead of StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter

Is there any objection against using

```
    final foo = Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    ...
    });
```

instead of

```
    class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(Build context) {
      ...
      }
    }
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Builder` instead of making a proper subclass has flaws.

Flutter's widget system uses the `runtimeType` variable to determine how it should behave.

To be more specific, when `runtimeType` changes, Flutter will *unmount* the previous widget tree at that location, and then mount the new one.

But by using *Builder* the `runtimeType` never changes, and it confuses the framework.

This, in turn, means that by using `Builder` instead of making a *StatelessWidget* subclass, it could have undesired behaviors like reusing the state of the previous widget tree.

---

For the sake of an example, consider that we want to switch between two different kinds of widget – both of which instantiate a *TextField*.

With builders our two widgets would be:

```
final foo = Builder(builder: (_) => TextField());
final bar = Builder(builder: (_) => TextField());
```

then used this way:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return condition ? foo : bar;
}
```

With classes we'd have:

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(Build context) => TextField();
}

class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(Build context) => TextField();
}
```

used as such:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return condition ? Foo() : Bar();
}
```

At this point, we run our application and starts typing some things inside the text field from our `foo`/`Foo` widget.

And then we're doing an action that will switch to `bar`/`Bar`.

In this step, the result will vary depending on if you used a class or a `Builder`:

- using `foo`/`bar`, the text field inside `bar` shows the text you typed in the text field from `foo`.
- using `Foo`/`Bar` classes, this does not happen. The text field inside `Bar` correctly resets to its initial value.

Comment: That’s interesting. So whenever I need an independent screen, I have to introduce a new subclass of Widget.

Comment: ok nice explanation, but which is more performance efficient, the Builder Widget or the Stateless Widget, I ask this because I use the Builder just fine, but I don't know if I should switch to a stateless Widget.